# Passing over values from one method to another on

Tags: java, for-loop, palindrome

The purpose of my code is to determine if a string entered by a user is a palindrome (meaning that the spelling of the word backwards and normally is the same). I am supposed to do this using 2 methods, the first one (reverse) which reverses the word. In this method, the string of the reversed word is returned, but I need to use it on the other method (isPalindrome) to compare if both the original text and the reversed word are spelled the same. How do I use the string being returned in the reverse method on the method isPalindrome?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Palindromes
{
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Type in your text:");
      String palindrome = input.nextLine();
      reverse(palindrome);
      if(isPalindrome(palindrome))
      {
        System.out.println("Your word is a palindrome!");  
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("Your word isn't a palindrome!");  
      }
      
    }
    
    public static boolean isPalindrome(String text)
    {
       boolean value = false;
       if(reverse.equals(text)) 
       {
          value = true;    
       }
          return value;
    }
    
  
    public static String reverse(String text)
    {
        String reverse = "";
        for(int i = text.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            reverse = reverse + text.substring(i, i+1);
        }
        return reverse;
       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `isPalindrome()` method, you  just need to call:

```
 return text.equals(reverse(text));
```

No need for the intermediate boolean `value`.

And to take it one step further, no need for the reverse logic either, since you can just use [`StringBuilder.reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse--).